# Changes in society under constant threat

Tags: society, aliens, apocalypse

Let's imagine a situation: one day without any preconditions Earth was attacked by unknown beings. They do not have firearms, but they have a sharp and durable blades. They walk pretty slow and have poor eyesight. Their size and weight approximately correspond to the average person. The number corresponds to the number of people around.

They appear out of nowhere - teleported directly on the surface of the planet, in all points where there is nothing to prevent them from freely stand - on city streets, inside homes, shelters, bank vaults, on the roofs of the buildings. After the appearance they attack people, break everything that comes their way, especially high-tech stuff. Aliens do not spare anyone or anything. They particularly focused on hi-tech and attack people only if they are too close or attacking them first. They show no signs of intelligence. They act mostly unconsciously.

They seek not to kill people but to destroy the high-tech stuff. If people decide to escape - they will not pursue them. The number of attackers is always roughly equal to the number of people around - in densely populated areas will be a lot of aliens, in sparsely populated - a few, where there are no people - and no aliens. The choice of teleportation point is completely random - they may appear far away from the people, and may be close, but never close enough be forced to attack immediately (therefore rarely appear inside the houses where the people are present).

As not intelligence creatures they are trying to destroy the tech, because experiencing some unpleasant sensation from it. So they attack in the first place that exudes the most "technical" effect. Nobody knows what exactly feel alien - electromagnetic fields, radiation or vibration, but they attacks in mainly the most complex and large-scale technical objects.

And an hour later they disappear as quickly as it appeared, along with the bodies of dead aliens.
After a few days the situation repeats, and will continue to be repeated once every few days (period not constant and varies between 3-5 days). The world is almost apocalyptic.

Aliens do not care about how much of them die during this attacks, and almost do not have the instinct of self-preservation. The number of aliens that take part in the next attack always will be approximately equal to the number of people in a particular area. Attacks in different parts of the World happen mostly daytime.

**Q:** What long-term changes occur in society, government, army and religion while there is a constant periodic threat? Whether the army can effectively resist the new enemy that appears in the middle of military bases, inside the barracks and staffs? Do people become more evil in an environment where no one monitors compliance of the law? Which of the life support systems and social benefits will be broken? (power supply, water supply, production of food, etc.)

*P.S. I am afraid that the question can be counted as too broad. If so, I'll try to narrow it down to just the question about a society.*

Comment: you used "few days" but I assume that the attacks are randomly paced. Am I right? And second, do the aliens spare someone or something? (Espcially hospitals, schools)

Comment: Also, after (say) two attacks, there will be lots of causalities on alien side. I assume the number of aliens is still the same and they do not care about how much of them die during this attack

Comment: If right now competent melee combatants suddenly appeared in every bedroom and office in equal numbers to people there, and started attacking, then after five minutes human society would cease to exist. Knife attacks result in lethal wounds in seconds. All civilians would die; most military or police units aren't at a state of active readiness and would be slaughtered at their barracks or homes. The following couple attacks would cleanse the world as people have to sleep and for this attack perimeter defense is not useful; but the first attack would be enough to end the world was we know it.

Comment: Are there some limits to where the aliens can teleport? Nuclear bunkers, for example? Do they kill only people who get in their way, or randomly slaughter innocents? What sort of infrastructure do they target? Can we kill them with regular firearms/blades/electricity? Are they organic, or mechanical in question. Are they wearing power-suits of some sort, or are they organic, and their flesh exposed? Do they breathe our air directly, or wear some sort of filtering system? How strong are they compared to humans? Can individual aliens teleport around while they attack, or only to arrive/leave?

Comment: You're right, this really is ***far too broad***. Take a look at the questions I've asked, please, and try to elaborate. As @Peteris points out, if these aliens field an equal number of warriors as the population of the Earth and instantly teleport them into our homes/military bases then humanity is doomed. There should be a lot fewer of them than us (remember than only a very small percentage of humans are warriors - we have women, children, the elder, etc.). They should have some sort of flaw/weakness that we can start exploiting quickly, otherwise it's all over but the diabolical laughter.

Comment: Also, will dead aliens teleport back too? Are we able to capture at least one alien or are these attacks simple "deus ex machina" ?

Comment: Another key question: what are their targeting priorities? Do they attack human beings with the intent of simply slaughtering us? Do they target "technology"? If so, what sort of technology? Individual cellphones and laptops? In that case they're gonna be busy. Do they attack factories, and power plants with the purpose of rendering them useless? You need to describe their behavior and perceived intentions. Can we communicate with them? Capture them and research their DNA, biology?

Comment: @PavelJanicek, @ AndreiROM, I've edited question.

Comment: This question has a lot of potential. Don't be dismayed if it is put on hold. Simply flesh it out and you have my promise that I will vote to reopen. I look forward to answering your updated question! PS: I just read your edit. It's much better, but there are still many questions left to answer. For example, if the aliens don't wear a breathing apparatus we may be able to simply start spraying poison to kill them as soon as they teleport in. Think about what I've asked and try to flesh in some more details (do it in bullet form if you think it will be more obvious to ppl)

Comment: Also, flesh it out to the point where we have at least some chance to survive, especially if you care about long term effects. Still, long term effect is: "All humans die." (And in fact, they die in less than 1 year as far as scope of the question stands)

Comment: @PavelJanicek, Let's say they do not tend to kill particularly people.

Comment: @Exerion each edit is getting there. What about bedroom of sleeping people? Lots of sleeping people use smart watches. Will they be killed because of the watch? People have now better chances of survival, but still bit too low

Comment: I have to go now, I'll polish this question more tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the army: the Army would have almost full control of the country. Martial law would definitely be declared since the enemy can teleport in at any time they would be constant Patrols roming me in the streets. Cameras to be set up monitoring every public area ready to automatically send out an alert if the aliens teleported in. The military probably start drafting people again as they will need it and enormously large military to Patrol the largest possible area.  People's perception of military would change as well, since they would literally be risking their lives to save the public they would probably receive even more respect then they do now.

Religious: Many religious leaders should probably see these creatures as demons or some sort of sign of the end. Studying The Book of Revelations would probably be become very important, as people would look for Clues about these creatures in the book.

Overall culture: the world is divided into two areas. Hi-Tech areas and low tech areas.

The high-tech areas would be the places where the military patrolled man killed on Aliens before they could destroy any infrastructure.

Sadly though no matter how large the military was they can't Patrol everything. So a lot of people would still be at risk of an alien attack. Quickly though they would realize that the aliens mainly Target places with large amounts of Technology so they would set up safe with very little Tech allowed. This is how the low-tech zones would come about.

More overall culture: everyone would have some sort of self-defense training. And the military would encourage people to carry guns on them. That way they could serve to slow the aliens down long enough for military patrol to get there.